# NamedParameterJdbcTemplate how return only one row?

Tags: spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have select:

```
SELECT hz FROM my_tablw WHERE id=1
```

It return me 1 row and 1 column:

```
hz
some data
```

I have

```
 @Autowired
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
```

And I need make query and return 1 row - String `some data`.
I create

```
jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT hz FROM my_tablw WHERE id=:id", insertManagerParameters, (rs, rowNum) -> {
            if (rs.next()) {
                return rs.getString(1);
            }
            return "";
        });
```

but this method return `List<String>`

Answer (score 4):

I would use the `queryForObject` method, like:

```java
jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT hz FROM my_tablw WHERE id=:id", insertManagerParameters, String.class);
```

Which should return a `String` with the query results.

Comment: what is the data type for insertManagerParameters?

Answer (score 0):

```
MapSqlParameterSource paramSource = new MapSqlParameterSource();
paramSource.addValue("id", id);
return this.customNamedParameterJdbcTemplate.getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(sqlConsultarPorId, paramSource,new MapeoReserva());
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts. That's especially important when there's already an existing answer that's been validated by the community. Under what conditions might your approach be preferred? Are you taking advantage of new capabilities?